# Using grep to help subset a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am having trouble subsetting my data.  I want the data subsetted on column x, where the first 3 characters begin G45.

My data frame:

```
x <- c("G448", "G459", "G479", "G406")  
y <- c(1:4)
My.Data <- data.frame (x,y)
```

I have tried:

```
subset (My.Data, x=="G45*")
```

But I am unsure how to use wildcards.  I have also tried grep() to find the indicies:

```
grep  ("G45*", My.Data$x)
```

but it returns all 4 rows, rather than just those beginning G45, probably also as I am unsure how to use wildcards.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward using `[` to extract:

`grep` will give you the position in which it matched your search pattern (unless you use `value = TRUE`).

```
grep("^G45", My.Data$x)
# [1] 2
```

Since you're searching within the values of a single column, that actually corresponds to the row index. So, use that with `[` (where you would use `My.Data[rows, cols]` to get specific rows and columns).

```
My.Data[grep("^G45", My.Data$x), ]
#      x y
# 2 G459 2
```

---

The help-page for `subset` shows how you can use `grep` and `grepl` with `subset` if you prefer using this function over `[`. Here's an example.

```
subset(My.Data, grepl("^G45", My.Data$x))
#      x y
# 2 G459 2
```

---

As of R 3.3, there's now also the `startsWith` function, which you can again use with `subset` (or with any of the other approaches above). According to the help page for the function, it's considerably faster than using `substring` or `grepl`.

```
subset(My.Data, startsWith(as.character(x), "G45"))
#      x y
# 2 G459 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the `stringr` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
My.Data %>% filter(str_detect(x, '^G45'))
```

You may not use `'^'` (starts with) in this case, to obtain the results you need