# how do you subset data frame based on grep

Tags: regex, r

I need to subset a data frame based on not including some strings. My data frame like this:

```
dput(dd)
structure(list(TimeStamp = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2016-04-18 00:30:00", 
"2016-04-18 01:10:00", "2016-04-18 01:20:00"), class = "factor"), 
    User = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("App", "Error", 
    "Web"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("TimeStamp", "User"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

when I try this:

```
dd[dd$User !=grep("Err*", dd),]
```

I get an empty data frame. I need to be able to use grep.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? Also, see [*Using grep to help subset a data frame in R*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311386/using-grep-to-help-subset-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Have you looked at `grepl`? I think you want: `dd[!grepl("Err.*", dd$User), ]`.

Comment: You should check out `grepl` instead of `grep`, but for this specific case, the problem is that `grep` is returning the index, not the value, of the pattern found. So you're asking R to subset where `dd$User != 2` in this case.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want `Err*` as your regex pattern? That is trying to match an "E", an "r', and 0 or more "r" after that. Do you want it to be `Err.*` instead?

Comment: `dd[grep("^Err.*", dd$User), ]` - right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think if you add `!` you'll have it. I believe OP wants to remove all rows that have an Error.

Comment: Yeah, but I am sure it is a dupe that is why I closed the question. Unless the pattern is an issue, there is no reason for reopening I believe.