# Using grepl to subset dataframe containing the same mentioning of some text in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, grepl

I'm working on a dataframe (`account`) with two columns containing "posting" IP location (in the column `city`) and the locations at the time when those accounts were first registered (in the column `register`). I'm using `grepl()` to subset rows whose posting location and register location are both from the state of New York (NY). Below are part of the data and my code for subsetting the desired output:

```css
account <- data.frame(city = c("Beijing, China", "New York, NY", "Hoboken, NJ", "Los Angeles, CA", "New York, NY", "Bloomington, IN"),
register = c("New York, NY", "New York, NY", "Wilwaukee, WI", "Rochester, NY", "New York, NY", "Tokyo, Japan"))

sub_data <- subset(account, grepl("NY", city) == "NY" & grepl("NY", register) == "NY")

sub_data
[1] city     register
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

My code didn't work and returned 0 row (while at least two rows should have met my selection criterion). What went wrong in my code? 
I have referenced [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311386/using-grep-to-help-subset-a-data-frame-in-r) before lodging this question.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue with the example.  I get 4 rows with that code

Comment: Try: `subset(account, grepl("NY", city) & grepl("NY", register))`.  Currently, your code will return cases that are both NY and both not NY.

Comment: @akrun It indeed does not produce the issue as described by the OP, however `grepl("NY", city) == grepl("NY", register)` will also return the rows both *not* having NY (in this case rows 3 & 6) whereas  `grepl("NY", city) & grepl("NY", register)` seems what the OP wants

Comment: It's been edited, sorry for the confusion and I'm trying out the solutions you suggested.

Comment: @ChrisT. `grepl` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE` as described in `?grepl`: "grepl returns a logical vector (match or not for each element of x)" so it makes no sense to compare this to a character (i.e. NY) as you did in `grepl("NY", city) == "NY"` instead you want to check whether **both** are true as suggested by @H1

Comment: @CodeNoob many thanks, you recommended method works better for large dataset like the one I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `grepl` already returns a logical vector, so just use the following:

```r
sub_data <- subset(account, 
                   grepl("NY", city) & grepl("NY", register)
                   )
```

By using something like `grepl("NY", city) == "NY"` you are asking R if any values in `FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE` are equal to `"NY"`, which is of course false.